# Email tracking tools, How it works?

Tags: email, tracking

Did you work with email tracking tools like "GetNotify.com"?

I want to know how it works, with details.

In my opinion we have to create a php code that contains img tag, but I don't know how can I attach this on email content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://www.getnotify.com/faq/#How_does_GetNotify_Email_tracking_work) FAQ entry, they insert an invisible image into the e-mail.

The idea behind this technique is that, upon e-mail opening, that image is downloaded from their server, providing them the IP address and the timestamp. Although, relying on the image being fetched, this service fails as soon as the image is not fetched (which you can configure many e-mail clients to do). EDIT: There is also a FAQ [entry](http://www.getnotify.com/faq/#Why_some_of_my_Emails_are_not_tracked) on that topic.

Inserting such an image into an e-mail is fairly simple: You need to get the e-mail html content and insert a new node. This is the second drawback: It fails when you use text messages. Instead, you would have to create a new HTML message.